# How to access pivoted columns in another sql query?

Tags: sql, pivot

I have a CTE which will create a Pivoted Dataset. After the creation of dataset, I want to access pivoted columns in another sql query. Can i Do that?

If you see below Screen shot I want to Access SW,AS,FG  columns in another select statement. How can I write the select statement

select SW,AS,FG.... FROM CTE...??

[image]

Comment: Which database is this for? Typically, you can create a table (even temporary) based on the results of a query.

Comment: Creating a result set may work. But I also wanted to know that the above columns can be used in a sql query as I wanted to use result set in another query

Comment: Yes, they can, but depending on the database, the syntax will be different. You can "dump" the results of the pivot into a table, temporary table, or variable (if that's what T-SQL calls it). You can then run a query against that.

Comment: Please tag your database. No two SQL dialects are the same.

Comment: I am using Snowflake database

Comment: from site [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) **DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc**.—copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your Valuable Inputs. I got the answer from snowflake documentation. We can Access the columns as "'COLUMN_NAME'"

Thanks